# The centreon poller does not run after exporting the configuration

Tags: poller, centreon-api

I want to connect my poller to start monitoring. Unfortunately when exporting the configuration, the poller does not start running

[View no executed poller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM1Vp.png)  (NON)

I tried to change the IP of the poller, restart the gorgon services of the two machines, nothing worked.

Anyone have an idea of ​​the solution?

Answer (score 0):

One common oversight on fresh installs is to not disable the firewall and the selinux. From personal experience, it may help to restart all processes in the command line after the first config export attempt from the web interface (*Configuration > Pollers > Export Configurations*).

**On pollers:**

```
systemctl enable centreon centengine
```

**On Central:**

```
systemctl restart php-fpm httpd24-httpd centreon cbd centengine gorgoned
```

Otherwise, I might need more information. If your issue hasn't been resolved yet, mind sharing:

- Your centreon version (from the capture I'd guess Centreon 22.04)
- You install medium (from source, packages, OVA/VM)
- Your distro

You may find some more clues in the logs:

**PHP error logs**

For version using PHP 7.2 or 7.3 on centOs 8 or PHP 8

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm/centreon-error.log
```

For version using PHP 7.3 on centOs 7

```
tail -f /var/opt/rh/rh-php73/log/php-fpm/centreon-error.log
```

For version using PHP 7.2 on centOs 7

```
tail -f /var/opt/rh/rh-php72/log/php-fpm/centreon-error.log
```

**centreon-engine logs (*On Central and on Poller*)**

```
tail -f /var/log/centreon-engine/centengine.log
```

**centreon-broker logs (*On Central*)**

```
tail -f /var/log/centreon-broker/central-broker-master.log
```

**centreon gorgone logs (*On Central and on Poller*)**

```
tail -f /var/log/centreon-gorgone/gorgoned.log
```